# Problem with indefinite square roots

Tags: linear-algebra, arithmetic

I have a question which reads:

> If $$\sqrt{12 + \sqrt{12 + \sqrt{12 + \cdots\cdots}}} = x$$ Then the value of $x$ is *_*.

I think that we can write $$x^2 - 12 = \sqrt{12 + \sqrt{12 + \sqrt{12 + \cdots\cdots}}}$$

But the square roots never end!

Can anyone please give me tips and hints for this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

So we can write $$x^2-12=x$$ assuming the convergence of the series

Observe that $x>0$

Comment: @GaurangTandon, my pleasure. Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588414/textlet-y-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-what-is-the-nearest-val and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589288/sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-sqrt7-cdots-approximation

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2-12=x$$

On solving $x=4$ or $x=-3$

Comment: but clearly $x>0$ so?

Comment: $x$ can be negative

Comment: If you take the nonstandard view and take the negative number as *the* square root, then $x=-3$. However, taking the positive square roots is too steeped in tradition and is the *standard* square root. So the answer is $4$.