# Calculating $ x= \sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{ 4+\dots}}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

If $ x= \sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{ 4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{ 4+\sqrt{4-\dots}}}}}} $
then find value of 2x-1

I tried the usual strategy of squaring and substituting the rest of series by x again but could not solve.

Comment: You have to write the square roots **clearly**: are they nested each one in the preceeding one(s)? Are they separated...? What's the pattern of the signs? Or is there only *one* minus sign there?

Comment: they are nested, i tried but could not get it better looking, minus is alternating

Comment: If the minus signs are alternate then why did you write that rightmost + sign there? That should be a minus sign...shouldn't it?

Comment: changed it now , hope it is clear

Comment: I edited it. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @JackM Good edit, because that was no hs algebra problem I have ever seen.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a solution that uses the fact that if $x = \cos^2{\theta}$, then $2x - 1 = \cos{2\theta}$.

Comment: thanks jack, you got it right, am weak in mathjax

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588414/textlet-y-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-sqrt5-what-is-the-nearest-val

Comment: Note that we need to show the sequence converges before we can use the methods in the answers below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you mean
$$ x=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4\pm\ldots}}}}}$$
so that
$$ \begin{align}x&=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-x}}\\
 x^2&=4+\sqrt{4-x}\\
 (x^2-4)^2&=4-x\\
 0 &= x^4-8x^2+x+12= (x^2-x-3)(x^2+x-4)\end{align}$$
Since clearly $x\ge \sqrt 4=2$, the second factor is $x^2+x-4\ge2>0$, which leaves us with the positive solution $x=\frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}\approx 2.3027756 $ from the first factor.

Comment: how did you factorize this 4th order equation?

Comment: @raj I'm not sure there is a neat way, but some brute force handles it. To show that there is not a factor $x-k$ with $k$ rational, [test all possible rational solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). They are $\{\pm 1,\pm 2, \pm 3, \pm 4, \pm 6, \pm 12 \}$, not impossible to check by hand. The only possibility now is that the polynomial is $(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$. Using the constraints, solving a system of equations and testing the solutions gives the desired factorization.

Answer (score 4):

We have

$$-\left((x^2-4)^2-4\right)=x\iff  x^4-8x^2+x+12= (x^2+x-4)(x^2-x-3) =0$$
solve this equation and notice that $x\ge2$ we find that the acceptable answer is 
$$x=\frac12\sqrt{13}+\frac12$$
hence
$$2x-1=\sqrt{13}$$

Answer (score 4):

Since $$x=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\cdots}}}},$$ you have $$x^2=4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\cdots}}},$$ so $$(x^2-4)^2=4-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\cdots}}.$$ Hence, $$(x^2-4)^2=4-x,$$ which you can try to solve.

Comment: Don't you think that we also need to show first that this sequence converges?

Comment: @User Not sure really - as symbol pushing goes the original sequence is contained in the final quartic equation, so solving that we get $x$ which is a finite number. I guess it would be rigorous to show the sequence converges, in and of itself, but I did not set out to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I misread the excercise but still the method I used applies. The first step has to be done twice and then a polynomial equation of degree 4 has to be solved.

$x=\sqrt{ \left( 4+...\right.} \underbrace{\Rightarrow}_{\text{square and }-4} x^{2}-4=\sqrt{ \left( 4+...\right.}=x \Rightarrow 0=x^{2}-x-4$

which is an easy to solve polynomial equation, the solutions are $\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+4}$ and $\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+4}$.

Comment: You misread the expression. You need to square over again as the second one is $4-$ instead of $4+$.

Comment: oooh, yes! haven't seen that. but the technique to apply stays the same. you have to do the first step twice then and solve a polynomial equation of degree 4.

Comment: Of course your method is perfectly valid. But you end up with a quartic which is much harder to solve than a quadratic. Well that one is not too bad. You should edit your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution without complex factorization:

Let,

$ x= \sqrt{4+\sqrt{4-\sqrt{ 4+\dots}}} $

$ y= \sqrt{4-\sqrt{4+\sqrt{ 4-\dots}}} $

Clearly,

$x = \sqrt{4 + y} \implies x^2 - y = 4$    (i)

$y = \sqrt{4 - x} \implies y^2 + x = 4$    (ii)

from (i) and (ii) we get,

$x^2 - y = y^2 + x$

$\implies (x+y)(x-y) = x+y$

Since, $x,y \ge 0$, we have $x+y \ne 0$

So, $x = y + 1$   (iii)

Putting (iii) in (i) or (ii) we get:

$x = \frac{\sqrt{13}+1}{2}$.